# Removing MacCleanse Helper

Tags: applications, macos

While looking at the activity monitor it occurred to me that I've a *Mac Cleanse Helper* process visible in the *Energy* tab. I might have installed this program in past but I got rid of it. How can I completely remove all the related files from the system?

[image: Mac Cleanse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs that install system components can't be uninstalled by simply throwing them in the Trash.

Usually an Uninstaller is provided in the original .dmg file, or can sometimes done from within the app itself.

If you delete the app, you may be too late to use that method.

Most companies that make apps which must be correctly uninstalled will have instructions on their own site as to how to achieve this, either by re-downloading the original .dmg, or they may provide a dedicated uninstaller app.

Koingo has such an app listed on its [MacCleanse Manual page](http://www.koingosw.com/products/maccleanse/manual.php#entryid95)

Direct link - 
http://www.koingosw.com/products/maccleanse/download/maccleanse4_uninstaller.zip